# Typescript const assertion (`as const`) with nested array

Tags: typescript

Using `as const` in the example below gives the error:

> The type 'readonly [{ readonly name: "some-repo"; readonly type: RepoType.API; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'RepoMeta[]'.

```
export enum RepoType {
  API = 1 << 0,
  UI = 1 << 1,
  Config = 1 << 2,
  ThirdParty = 1 << 3,
}

export const Org: OrgMeta = {
  name: "MyOrg",
  repos: [ {             // error is here
    name: "some-repo",
    type: RepoType.API,
  } ]
} as const;

export type OrgMeta = {
  name: string;
  repos: RepoMeta[];
};

export type RepoMeta = {
  name: string;
  type: RepoType;
};
```

I was able to get around this by removing `as const` and marking all 4 properties in both `type`s as `readonly`:

```
export type OrgMeta = {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly repos: RepoMeta[];
};

export type RepoMeta = {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly type: RepoType;
};
```

But I'm not sure why `as const` didn't work. [Playground example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwErEgFQJ5jBwDeAsAFBxwCCACgJJwC8cAjHADwdwAMANBSoBVRi3Zc2AynADCERADMAlgHNmbTtwBMUqjgAWSqABNaAQ1h5147gGYpAXwoVQkWHADG8gM7wA8lAqAFxwASoAssAwZupk0ohmqMAhAETheGEpunBQ2BDeIQDaJIJUcAlJqd4QSQC0uZBZpVQwBMmYefiEAHR09NkOcAC6FINm3p4+MADczuSu0PCthKGBkdGxpblmxvIANlYV7b5QSogqs9Lbu4gHOXkFHZDrZoVDlw6XLuCLcMtEWGeURiLDiVGu+0OiWOMFO50u4OAO0hfzaIUBEC6wA+lyAA)

Comment: What were you trying to achieve with the `as const`?

Comment: You can get around it by just removing `as const` (without touching your other types) or making your `repos` property a `readonly RepoMeta[]` (`Array<T>` is assignable to `ReadonlyArray<T>` but not vice versa.  Unless you need your arrays to be mutable, `ReadonlyArray<T>` is more permissive and therefore recommended in situations like this.)  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nryg2w) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?